# Object Lifecycle Management Firebase Storage

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

How to setup object lifecycle management in a firebase storage bucket. For example if i want to delete the files after 30 days of upload. Cannot find any documentation for firebase, but i can find for Google Storage.

Can we setup Object Lifecycle Management in a firebase bucket or any alternatives if there is no official method to do so.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Firebase Storage Product Manager here:

Because Firebase Storage is backed by Google Cloud Storage, all the features of GCS, including [Object Lifecycle Management](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/lifecycle), are available to Firebase Storage developers.

Object Lifecycle Management enables you to move data from one bucket type (such as Standard) to another (such as Durable Reduced Availability or Nearline), or delete an object after a certain amount of time.

Here's an example of how to delete objects after 30 days:

```
// 30DayTTL.json
{
    "rule":
    [
      {
        "action": {"type": "Delete"},
        "condition": {"age": 30}
      }
    ]
}
```

You can use that in the [gsutil](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil) tool like this:

```
gsutil lifecycle set 30DayTTL.json gs://bucket.appspot.com
```

Note that this applies to all objects in a bucket, so if you want more granular Time to Live (TTL) functionality, you'll want to use multiple buckets or roll your own system as mentioned in the other answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could try maintaining a database record of the object created in firebase storage along with its creation time and use an external script running in some corn job service to delete old objects. (Note: You could instead put the creation time inside the meta data of the object in firebase storage)

There is no other way to achieve it both officially & unofficially.

Comment: Good answer Debanjan. There is nothing built-in to automatically delete items after a certain period. So rolling your own is the way to go.

Comment: Is your comment still relevant? @FrankvanPuffelen